# Factory Bot HABTM nil value in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am getting a (frustrating!) error when running rspec (with Factory Bot) tests for my Rails app. I'm seeing the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation:
        Mysql2::Error: Field 'group_id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `groups_users` VALUES ()
```

It is intermittent - different tests will throw the error on different runs - which might suggest a race condition?

My models are configured as:

```
User habtm Groups
Groups habtm Users
```

Staff members MUST belong to one group - with a validation of:

```
validates :groups, presence: { message: 'Staff must be in at least one group' }, if: :staff?
```

**Users**

```
factory :a_staff_member, class: User do
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    username { "#{first_name}_#{last_name}".downcase.gsub(/[^a-z]/i, '') }
    email { "#{first_name}.#{last_name}@example.ac.uk".downcase }
    user_type { :staff }
    groups {|s| [s.association(:group)]}
end
```

**Groups**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :group do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "Group Number #{n}" }
    sequence(:short_title) { |n| "GRP#{n}" }
    sequence(:url_slug) { |n| "grp#{n}" }
  end
end
```

The common factor in all of the failing tests is the User creation factory (and the Groups creation given a User MUST belong to a group) - so this is where I have been focussing my efforts.

Given that the error is on the groups_users table I'm guessing that it's trying to save an entry to the join table before the group exists in the groups table?

Based on other SO posts and trawling the Internet, I've tried various ways of setting the group:

```
1) groups {|s| [s.association(:group)]}

2) after(:build) {|user| user.groups = [create(:group)]}

3) groups {[FactoryBot.create(:group)]}
```

The users are just instantiated via

```
let!(:staff_user) { FactoryBot.create(:a_staff_member) }
```

in the individual specs - so nothing exciting there.

However, no mater how I create the groups in the factories it doesn't make any difference - and I've run out of ideas - any pointers or suggestions would be gratefully received!

Comment: That validation won't work because its a catch-22. You have to insert the user record into the database before you can insert anything into the join table as the join table requires a user id (and the record does not have an id until its inserted). You need to rethink this from square one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I should probably add - this is only an issue when run in the tests - the code itself works (I can create users via the UI successfully - it also works intermittently in the test suite). There isn't a circular dependency - as long as the group exists the user can be added to it. As far as I can tell, it is an issue with the way I am creating the group in the factory and when it is persisted so it can be linked over the habtm relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I think trying to change the equality with concatenation might work.

I'd add `after(:create) { |user| user.groups << create(:group) }`

Moving to `after(:create)` is the main thing here as the problem you are facing also seems to be trying to add a join table record for a record that is not created yet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this doesn't work because there is a validation that a user must belong to one group. Calling the assignment of the group in an after create causes this validation to fail. NB it is the group_id that is nil in the error message - as if the group hasn't been created prior to trying to join to it when saving the user... I also tried switching the assignment to a concatenation - but this had no effect :( Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to track down the issue. After putting some comprehensive debug messages around the point in the factory that the group was created and assigned to the user, it became clear that the error message relating to nil values in the join table between these was, in fact, a red herring and being caused outside of the factory.

I believe the issue was caused by the user session/log in not being cleaned up between tests from Capybara.

Adding:

```
config.after :each do
  Warden.test_reset!
end
```

to `/spec/spec_helper.rb` appears to have resolved the issue. Hopefully the hair pulled out during this investigation will grow back!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it might work if you change like this.

```
 from
 after(:build) {|user| user.groups = [create(:group)]}

 to
 after(:create) {|user| user.groups = [create(:group)]}
```

Once a user id is created by running "create", then "users.groups" will be acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - unfortunately, that doesn't work because it is triggered after the user is created - this will cause the validation that the user must belong to at least one group to fail. I was hoping that by putting a call to create a group in an after build, it would ensure that the group record exists when the user is saved so there is a record to join to when creating the user!